# Specify the Phase based on the Dates

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-dates

I have dates listed in Column A and I want to convert them to Phases in Column B; e.g. if the date is >= 5 Feb 2024 is equal to Phase 1 & if the date is >= 1 March 2024 is equal to Phase 2 and so on.

So far I've used this formula:

`=IFERROR(ARRAYFORMULA(IFS(A:A<>"", IF(A:A >= DATE(2024,2,5), "Phase 1",IF(A:A >= DATE(2024,3,1), "Phase 2",IF(A:A >= DATE(2024,4,6), "Phase 3",IF(A:A >= DATE(2024,5,4), "Phase 4",IF(A:A >= DATE(2024,6,8), "Phase 5",IF(A:A >= DATE(2024,7,6), "Phase 6",IF(A:A >= DATE(2024,8,10), "Phase 7")))))))) ),"")`

The problem with this formula is it always return Phase 1 no matter what the dates are. I have tried changing the Date format in column A but to no avail.

I'm open to any other method to group the date ranges into phases.

[Link to my example spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1hZ8ksyhsXNRvCvLhk9Y5uEpQ6tNc5XjLVCijD11Jmp8/edit?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `ifs()`, like this:

```
=arrayformula(ifs( 
  A1:A = "", iferror(ø), 
  istext(A1:A), na(), 
  not(isdate_strict(A1:A)), na(), 
  A1:A < --"2024-02-05", iferror(ø), 
  A1:A < --"2024-03-01", "Phase 1", 
  A1:A < --"2024-04-06", "Phase 2", 
  A1:A < --"2024-05-04", "Phase 3", 
  A1:A < --"2024-06-08", "Phase 4", 
  A1:A < --"2024-07-06", "Phase 5", 
  A1:A < --"2024-08-10", "Phase 6", 
  true, "Phase 7" 
))
```

See [ifs()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/7014145) and [double unary](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33500747/13045193).

Answer (score 0):

Similar approach to [doubleunary](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/175143) but using a sorted lookup table and VLOOKUP instead of IFS:

```
=IFNA(ARRAYFORMULA(VLOOKUP(A2:A,
   { "2/5/2024"*1,  "Phase 1";
     "3/1/2024"*1,  "Phase 2";
     "4/6/2024"*1,  "Phase 3";
     "5/4/2024"*1,  "Phase 4";
     "6/8/2024"*1,  "Phase 5";
     "7/6/2024"*1,  "Phase 6";
     "8/10/2024"*1, "Phase 7"},2)))
```

**OR** the same formula using a table to manage the options:

```
=IFNA(ARRAYFORMULA(VLOOKUP(A2:A, C2:D8, 2)))
```

|  | C | D |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **1** | **Date** | **Phase** |  |
| **2** | 02/05/2024 | Phase 1 |  |
| **3** | 03/01/2024 | Phase 2 |  |
| **4** | 04/06/2024 | Phase 3 |  |
| **5** | 05/04/2024 | Phase 4 |  |
| **6** | 06/08/2024 | Phase 5 |  |
| **7** | 07/06/2024 | Phase 6 |  |
| **8** | 08/10/2024 | Phase 7 |  |